# Wanted: Android Tablet As Extended Display For Windows 7 using TeamViewer - via USB only - cannot spoof fake VGA display

Tags: windows-7, usb, multiple-monitors, android, teamviewer

I'm shopping for my first Android device, and I have a highly specific question which many hours of research has not answered.  However, to someone with knowledge in this area, it may be a no-brainer.  *I don't mind rooting the device (probably a Galaxy Tab A) if necessary.*

**Half my interest in buying an Android tablet involves using it as a second monitor for my Windows 7 PC.**

- I do not want to use wifi, internet, or other wireless methods to achieve  this - *USB only*
- I do not want to use paid applications, all of which have unequivocally appalling reviews

**My research has shown me that this is possible.**  However, the examples I found involved going through a local wifi network *(or trafficking through the internet - this was unclear)* using TeamViewer.  I found no instances of confirmation that the same can be achieved via a standard wired USB connection.

So my first question becomes:
**Can TeamViewer make use of a USB connection between an Android tablet and a Windows PC, and pipe all data through this connection alone?**

Furthermore, the two instances I found confirming that TeamViewer can facilitate this behavior involved using the same "fake monitor" trick on the Windows PC.

This "fake monitor" setup was achieved thanks to the GPU's unused VGA connection.  Presumably for compatibility, Windows 7 allows enabling an "undetected" VGA display *which need not actually exist to be treated as a valid display*.  **The only success stories I located involved TeamViewer viewing this nonexistent-but-enabled VGA display.**

**My PC does not feature a VGA port.**  Seems logical this is why, but at any rate, Windows 7 is hiding these options from me.  So this is presumably where my millage has varied from this novel solution.

So question two becomes:
**Is it possible to get this behavior without using TeamViewer to view a Fake VGA Display**
**-------- OR --------**
**Is it possible for me to create a valid Fake VGA Display without a hardware VGA port?**

If anyone has any definitive information on this topic, you would truly make my day.  I'm thoroughly tired of fruitless searching.  The answer to these questions will determine whether I make this significant purchase at all, so you'll be doing me a giant favor.

*My sincere thanks,*

Comment: This can be simplified by using a vga or hdmi cable and the required adapters on both ends. Usb ones are available.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, that sounds promising!  Can I ask that you be more specific?  What connects to what via what wires/adapters, and what applications will be involved?  The tablet's only wired interface is USB, and my GPU's only interfaces are a pair of D-Subs.

Comment: Just learned I also have an HDMI port on this GPU.  Who knew?  ;)

Comment: Excellent. I think you may have been over thinking it a bit. Which happens to the best of us!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an app called twomonUSB that can help you acheive this with a standard usb cable. 
[TwomonUSB](http://www.easynlight.com/en/twomonusb)

The app is $11 dollars but you will be able to use the usb charging cord that comes with your tablet so there will be no additional cost.

Comment: I've previously discovered this app (and its competitors) and find their polarized feedback very off-putting.  Though when it comes down to it, perhaps it's cheaper and less risky than the alternatives.  

I do appreciate your time spent assisting me, thanks very much!

Comment: Yup no problem. I would say its worth a try. It is designed to do exactly what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with a standard hdmi cable and the required adaptors.
**Usb to hdmi adaptor for PC**.
[image].
**HDMI cable**.
[image].
**HDMI to tablet**.
[image].

Comment: Been looking for 45 minutes, and I can't locate a suitable "HDMI to Tablet" style adapter.  

A few instances of adapters with the correct plugs, but none spoke about sending a signal TO the tablet.  They were all for playing Android media on a TV.  Most had conflicting "answers" about per-device compatibility.

They all had terrible reviews (or too few for comfort).  And the cost of these cables & adapters pushes me about 150% over budget.

Is there really no better way to achieve this setup?  Surely it's not such an uncommon desire.  USB-to-USB sounds so obvious and elegant.

Comment: Assuming I find suitable adapters to link a PC's HDMI port to an Android tablet's USB port, will my PC simply recognize the tablet as a display onto which I can extend the windows desktop?  Or would this functionality require the use of some kind of third-party app?

Comment: Yah it may work this way as the port on the tablet may be designed to only send video out.